# Project oxford vision API ocr exception Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I got a problem with OCR vision API in Xamarin wpf when taking picture on Iphone, while on Android it works perfect. 
Picking image from gallery on both Android and IOS also works correctly.

> `Thread started:  #11 Resolved pending breakpoint at 'OcrRecognitionPage.xaml.cs:60,1' to void ComputerVisionSample.OcrRecognitionPage.d__5.MoveNext () [0x00162].
>       Error while resolving expression: One or more errors occurred.` 
>       Thread finished:  #9
>       The thread 'Unknown' (0x9) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>       Thread finished:  #10
>       The thread 'Unknown' (0xa) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>       Thread started:  #12
>       Thread started:  #13
>       Thread started:  #14
>       Thread finished:  #8
>       The thread 'Unknown' (0x8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>       
>       `Unhandled Exception:
>       Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.ClientException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.ClientException' was thrown.
>       Thread finished:  #11`

Source code:

```
       public partial class OcrRecognitionPage : ContentPage
        {
            private readonly VisionServiceClient visionClient;
            string sourceLanguage = "en"; 
            string sourceText = ""; 
            public OcrRecognitionPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.visionClient = new VisionServiceClient("Your code here");
            }

            private async Task AnalyzePictureAsync(Stream inputFile)
            {
                if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Network error", "Please check your network connection and retry.", "OK");
                    return null;
                }

                OcrResults ocrResult = await visionClient.RecognizeTextAsync(inputFile);
                return ocrResult;
            }

            private async void TakePictureButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No camera available.", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    SaveToAlbum = false,
                    Name = "test.jpg"
                });

                if (file == null)
                    return;

                Image1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());

                var ocrResult = await AnalyzePictureAsync(file.GetStream());

                this.BindingContext = null;           
                this.BindingContext = ocrResult;
                sourceLanguage = ocrResult.Language;

                PopulateUIWithRegions(ocrResult);

            }

            private void PopulateUIWithRegions(OcrResults ocrResult)
            {
                // Iterate the regions
                foreach (var region in ocrResult.Regions)
                {
                    // Iterate lines per region
                    foreach (var line in region.Lines)
                    {
                        // For each line, add a panel
                        // to present words horizontally
                        var lineStack = new StackLayout
                        { Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal };
                        // Iterate words per line and add the word
                        // to the StackLayout
                        foreach (var word in line.Words)
                        {
                                Text = word.Text };

                            sourceText += textLabel.Text + " "; 

                            lineStack.Children.Add(textLabel);

                        }
                        // Add the StackLayout to the UI
                        this.DetectedText.Children.Add(lineStack);
                    }
                }
            }
     private async void UploadPictureButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("No upload", "Picking a photo is not supported.", "OK");
                    return;
                }
                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
                if (file == null)
                    return;
                Image1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());

                var ocrResult = await AnalyzePictureAsync(file.GetStream());

                this.BindingContext = ocrResult;
                sourceLanguage = ocrResult.Language;
                PopulateUIWithRegions(ocrResult);
            }
```

Did anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: For any method that is async void, you should use a try/catch block in case exceptions get thrown since there is no way for your calling code to handle the exception. Once you have these in place you should be able to put a breakpoint in your catch block and get more information about the error. Looking at ClientException in Oxford it seems that most of these are HTTP related, and either the Error property or inner exception should have more information.

Comment: Thanks for response. Handled exception. Output  :{Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.ClientError}                                                       Code: InvalidImageSize                                                                                       Message: Input image is too large

Comment: Seems pretty clear, looks like you will need to resize the image before uploading it for analysis

Comment: Solved using property CompressionQuality = 65  in StoreCameraMediaOptions method